# Injecting the functionality of one function into another larger function

Tags: javascript, dom

Fraking functioning functions, Functionman!

I have one big function that searches a DOM for one parameter and replaces it with another:

```
function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
        // Throw error here if you want...
        return;
    }
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
        new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
        childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes,
        cnLength = childNodes.length,
        excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
            (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data)) {
            continue;
        }
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
            frag = (function () {
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                wrap.innerHTML = html;
                while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}
```

Then I have another little function that takes a dollar amount and creates another number:

```
function = oppCostCalc(dollarAmount) {
    var wage = 7.25;
    var costNum = Number(dollarAmount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var oppCost = Math.round(costNum/wage);
    return  oppCost;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create one big function that searches a page for dollarAmount then replaces all occurrences with oppCost.

Can I just squeeze oppCostCalc into findAndReplace somehow? One of the main problems is that find and replace has both an input and output parameter and I need it to have only the input and use it to find the output. I've read some stuff about wrapping the two in another function but that seems a step backwards.

I'm not necessarily looking for a "here's your script" kind of answer just a solid push in the right direction. I'll come back and edit this post once I figure it out

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hum, a call like this `findAndReplace(someDollarAmount, oppCostCalc(someDollarAmount), searchNode)` should work. Don't mash the two functions together, that will be a step back, creating a new function is better to do the "mashing".

Comment: @ShanShan nope. Good Idea but it doesn't work. Another detail I forgot to mention was that I need the input parameter to be a regex.

Comment: Which parameter? And it changes nothing, regex or not, it's still a parameter. If you need it to be a specific object, you can build it before calling `findAndReplace()`, the third new function should do all the things needed.

Comment: @ShanShan So you're saying rather then merge the two functions I should split up findAndReplace()? One to find the input with the regex. Then oppCostCalc() to modify it. Then that's passed to another function that puts it in.The call line will look absurd but I'll give it a go.

Comment: No, you don't need to split anything. The current `findAndReplace()` works fine, right? If yes, just create a new function building the `replacement` parameter with the return of  `oppCostCalc()` and then call `findAndReplace()`. Something like this: https://jsbin.com/geriqovazo/1/edit?js